# Use Python and Java in Powershell without switching?

Tags: java, python, powershell

I have Python 2.7 and Java 1.8 on my computer. Is it possible to use both in Powershell without have to type in the whole SetEnvironmentVariable command every time I want to switch between them?

Comment: Not sure about which command are you using, are you setting the path? can't you just set all the needed environment variables at the beginning of the session (or at the system level)? otherwise, which conflicting variables do you have?

Comment: I used this command to set Java. Before I had use this except with the Python Path. can I set more than one path with this command? [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path","$env:Path;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin",

Comment: I don't know the exact powershell syntax, but you can just add everything you need to the path .  You are already correctly appending (not replacing) the java path to the pre-existing path, just add also the python path after a ; . Try also to print the path variable to check what is there

Comment: If you are always using the same python and java version, considering modifying permanetly the system path variable from the control panel http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: I put the python path after a ; in the system properties environment variables and now it's working! Thank You!